# How can I position absolutely a div in a table?

Tags: html, html-table, css-position

I'm trying to correct an old template which contains tables and not divs.

The whole template consists of tables.
I'm tyring to position an png image absolutely in the table, that is overlapping the background.

The code I've made is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="homepage.html">
            <div style="position:absolute;margin-top:-60px;margin-left:-18px;">                     
                   <img  src="images/header.png" width="280" height="120" alt="" border="0">
           </div>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that some browsers "miss" a pixel.

Is there any way to position absolutely an image in a table?

p.s. at the moment, I know that the best way is to use divs, but I shall not alter the whole template, just alter only the heading.

Comment: A `div` inside an `a` is an error. Don't use presentational attributes such as `border`. Positioning context depends on the parent DOM node's positioning context. And finally, What is "missing a pixel", exactly? What's the output you get, what's the output you expect?

Comment: thanks for replying,the image i have to align contains a straight line that must fit with the next image tha contains a straight line too.

Comment: So does it work when you put the `a` inside the `div` instead of the other way around? If not, are the images really 280x120 pixels, or does the browser need to resize them? Resizing may cause different round-off errors in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way:

```
   <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
                <div style="position:absolute;margin-top:-60px;margin-left:-18px;">                     
                       <a href="homepage.html">
                       <img  src="images/header.png" width="280" height="120" alt="" border="0">
                       </a>
               </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```